# Determine the character index of DOM element inside its owner document's html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Primarily, I need to convert selection ranges to indices in the source HTML. I was thinking there's a couple ways to do it manually, but is there a built in way to do it?

Some ideas:

- Clone the document. Remove the element and its subsequent siblings, and remove all the subsequent siblings of each of its ancestors. Then you just get the document HTML and get its length. o_O
- render the tags, text, etc to HTML myself, walking down the DOM tree. Also o_O

The performance could be improved by caching results. Then, if an ancestor already knows its position, it's a bit faster to compute the childs. But then maintaining the cache is another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a unique ID or class to it and then search for that in the whole document string?

Comment: +1 Brilliant. I'll mark as answer as soon as the 10 minute cool down period elapses...